# How Much Liquid Can I Put In My Cylinders Safely?

Tags: engine

I wanted to do a little bit of a "scientific" test to see how well a homebrew seafoam type mixture will dissolve carbon deposits on the cylinder crowns.  I thought of simply taking the plugs out and introducing a measured amount of the mixture into each cylinder with a syringe.  However, I don't want to put in too much and cause a hydrolock situation. How can I figure out what is a safe amount?  In general, and in my specific case.  In my specific case, I have a Nissan 1.6L 4 cylinder GA16DE engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I just realized if you know the engine displacement and compression ratio you should be able to figure this out pretty easily.

Even if I don't inject directly down the plug hole, but use the more traditional brake booster vacuum line method, I'd still like to know how much fluid I can safely pour down the vacuum line on the last gulp before stalling / shutting off the engine.

So I was just looking in "Engine Builder's Handbook" pg 103 and it has the following:

> CR = SV/CV + 1

Where SV is swept volume ( [engine displacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engine_displacement) ) of one cylinder and CV is combustion chamber volume.

To figure CV I just rewrite the equation as:

CV = SV/(CR-1)

So if I know the engine displacement is 1.6L then SV for a single cylinder will be 400cc and the GA16DE has published CR's of either 9.5:1 or 9.9:1 so I get the equation:

CV = 400/(9.5-1) = 47cc

So the combustion chamber volume above the piston at TDC will be 47cc.

So I guess that say 1/2 to 3/4 that volume would be more than safe and wouldn't cause [hydrolock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrolock).  Or say 150ml if I was pouring down the vacuum line.

Comment: While your math looks sound , personally, I would never fully trust theoretical math when my $1000 engine is on the line.  There are probably variables not accounted for.  I would recommend doing @rpmerf's method to verify your calculations.

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski That's why I would only use 1/2 to 3/4 of the calculated volume as a safety margin.  SA's Performance Engine Math gives the same calculation.  In this case, to me it seems "good enough".

Comment: Interesting calculation.  It should at least get you in the ballpark.  Either way, if your doing the vacuum line method, go slow until you stall it.  When it stalls, you will have MUCH less than the amount required to hydrolock it.  Anything you add after it stalls is just going to sit in the intake or at the back of the valves.

Answer (score 4):

Liquid cannot compress.  The volume of the cylinder is smallest when the cylinder is at TDC.

IF you know things like piston dish volume, head combustion chamber volume, head gasket thickness, you can calculate this volume.  I am assume you do not know these values...

Here is what I do.  Set the engine to TDC on #1.  Pull the plug.  Fill up the cylinder.  This is the maximum amount the cylinder can hold.  I would then remove about 20% of that leaving 80% in the cylinder.  Before starting your engine, suck out as much as you can.  You might even want to crank the engine over with the spark plugs out.  Be sure to clean the surrounding area before pulling the plugs to make sure nothing can get sucked in.

Also note that your rings are not 100% sealed.  Some of this mixture CAN leak past and get into your oil.

I personally would not add the mixture directly in the spark plug hole.  I've always added seafoam/power foam through a vacuum line or the throttle body on a running engine.  This also ensures the valves get cleaned.

Comment: It's still useful to have this number even if you use the vacuum line method.

Comment: I just came up with a definitive answer if you're interested.